# How to use variables in a GraphQL query?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql

So I have to make two queries. First will return an array with multiple objects and I want to get the ID of the first object to use it in my second query.

The problem is that I can't use `b_id: props.getBusiness.business[0]._id`

Any idea how can I work with this?

```
const GET_USER_BUSINESS = gql`
  query getUserBusiness {
    getUserBusiness {
        _id
    }
  }
`;

const GET_BUSINESS_JOBS = gql`
  query getBusinessJobs($b_id: ID!) {
    getBusinessJobs(b_id: $b_id ) {
        _id
        name
    }
  }
`;

export default compose(
    withApollo,
    graphql(GET_USER_BUSINESS,
        {
            name: "business"
        }),
    graphql(GET_BUSINESS_JOBS,
        {
            name: "jobs",
            options: (props) => (
                {
                    variables:
                    {
                        b_id: props.getUserBusiness.business[0].b_id
                    }
                }
            )
        })
)(ProposalContainer);
```

Comment: Do you control the server end of this too?

Comment: @DavidMaze no it is just a query

Comment: `getUserBusiness` sounds like it would return a single object and not an array... does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things. One, by default, the `graphql` HOC passes a prop called `data` down to the wrapped component with the query data. However, because you specify a `name` in the HOC's config, the prop will actually be called whatever name you pass it. In other words, you can access the `_id` this way:

```
props.business.getUserBusiness[0]._id
```

...if getUserBusiness returns an array. Otherwise:

```
props.business.getUserBusiness._id
```

Secondly, `props.business` will be undefined until the query completes. We probably don't want to send the `GET_BUSINESS_JOBS` query until we have an `_id` to work with. So we want to pass a `skip` function to the HOC's config:

```
export default compose(
    withApollo,
    graphql(GET_USER_BUSINESS,
        {
            name: "business"
        }),
    graphql(GET_BUSINESS_JOBS,
        {
            name: "jobs",
            skip: (props) => !props.business || !props.business.getUserBusiness[0]
            options: (props) => (
                {
                    variables:
                    {
                        b_id: props.business.getUserBusiness[0]._id
                    }
                }
            )
        })
)(ProposalContainer)
```